# How to get unit test method attributes at runtime from within an NUnit test run?

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, nunit

I store various information about a given test (IDs for multiple bug tracking systems) in an attribute like so:

```
[TestCaseVersion("001","B-8345","X543")]
public void TestSomethingOrOther()
```

In order to fetch this information during the course of a test, I wrote the below code:

```
     public string GetTestID()
     {
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace(1);
        StackFrame sf;
        for (int i = 1; i <= st.FrameCount; i++)
        {
            sf = st.GetFrame(i);
            if (null == sf) continue;
            MethodBase method = sf.GetMethod();
            if (method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestAttribute), true).Length == 1)
            {
                if (method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestCaseVersion), true).Length == 1)
                {
                    TestCaseVersion tcv =
                        sf.GetMethod().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestCaseVersion), true).OfType<TestCaseVersion>()
                            .First();
                    return tcv.TestID;
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is that when running tests through NUnit in Release mode, the method which should have the test name and these attributes is replaced by the following:

```
System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at NUnit.Core.Reflect.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object fixture, Object[] args)
```

**UPDATE**
For anyone who is interested, I wound up implementing the code in the following way (so that any of the attribute values could be accessed, without changing any of the existing code that uses TestCaseVersion attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class TestCaseVersion : PropertyAttribute
{
   public TestCaseVersion(string testCaseCode, string story, string task, string description)
   {
      base.Properties.Add("TestId", testCaseCode);
      base.Properties.Add("Description", description);
      base.Properties.Add("StoryId", story);
      base.Properties.Add("TaskId", task);
    }
}

public string GetTestID()
{
   return TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["TestId"];
}
```

Comment: Nice update!!! I would give you a second upvote if I could :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are OK with having a single-valued test case version string (i.e. `"001, B-8345, X543"` instead of `"001","B-8345","X543"`), you should be able to make use of the [TestContext](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=testContext&r=2.6) functionality available in *NUnit 2.5.7*  and higher.

Specifically, you could define and use a test context [Property](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=property&r=2.6) attribute *TestCaseVersion* like this:

```
[Test, Property("TestCaseVersion", "001, B-8345, X543")]
public void TestContextPropertyTest()
{
    Console.WriteLine(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["TestCaseVersion"]);
}
```

**UPDATE** BTW, If you *do* want to use a multi-valued representation of the test case version, you could define multiple properties, like this:

```
[Test, Property("MajorVersion", "001"), 
 Property("MinorVersion", "B-8345"), Property("Build", "X543")]
public void TestContextPropertyTest()
{
    Console.WriteLine(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["MajorVersion"]);
    Console.WriteLine(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["MinorVersion"]);
    Console.WriteLine(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["Build"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is the only solution I could find as well. I wish there was a way to get any other attributes of the actual test method, but this will have to do

Answer (score 0):

May be I don't understand your idea, but why not to use much simpler solution?

```
[TestCase(TestName = "001, B-8345, X543")]
public void TestSomethingOrOther()
```

Comment: I am happy with the TestName in the NUnit TestContext, but I want to supply multiple additional values simply by adding them to the attribute. If I use them in a TestCase attribute, I would have to add them as parameters to the test method, and they still would not be accessible without adding additional code to every test.

Comment: But how are you going to use `GetTestID()`, add additional info to assert messages?

Comment: I use GetTestID on a method that all the tests call, to log the results of the tests.