# How to get test case description?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, automated-tests

I have nunit test with some test cases.

```
[TestCase(1,Description="first")]
[TestCase(2, Description="second")]
public void A(int a)
{
    Assert.True(a==1);
}
```

How can I get description of each test case. I try do it at TestFinished() method of EventListener, but I can get only array of descriptions.

Comment: What for do you need test description?

Comment: I'd suggest that you write your test names to represent what you're testing. 

For example, in an mvc4 project I work on I'd name tests like this.

<Controller>_<Method>_input_is_null_NullArgumentException_Expected.

I've moved to this naming convention recently and been quite strict with, it's worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried NUnit's [CurrentContext](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testContext&r=2.6)?

Perhaps (I've not looked) the value of Description is in TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties, you'll need at least NUnit 2.6.2 see [NUnit 2.6.2 TestContext.CurrentContext always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528413/nunit-2-6-2-testcontext-currentcontext-always-null)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should see take a look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762648/how-to-get-unit-test-method-attributes-at-runtime-from-within-an-nunit-test-run)

But when I tried what is mentioned in this answer, it gave me the object of Properties List itself which unneeded,
It worked with me fine when I used instead:

```
TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Get("Description")
```

I hope it works with you too