# NUnit 2.6.2 TestContext.CurrentContext always null

Tags: c#, tdd, nunit, nunit-2.6.2

I'm trying to use the `TestContext.CurrentContext` of NUnit 2.6.2 but it's always null.

What I would like is to have an output with the result of tests, but if I run the following code I always get a `NullReferenceException` in the `TearDown` method.
All the properties inside Test and Result are throwing the exception.

```
[TestFixture]
public class UtilitiesTests
{
  [TearDown]
  public void TearDown()
  {
    //using console here just for sake of simplicity. 
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.FullName, TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status));
  }

  [Test]
  public void CleanFileName()
  {
    var cleanName = Utilities.CleanFileName("my &file%123$99\\|/?\"*:<>.jpg");
    Assert.AreEqual("my-efile12399---.jpg", cleanName);
  }
}
```

What I'm possibly doing wrong?

Comment: How are you running the tests?

Comment: I'm using coderush.I also tried with the Nunit Gui. Same behaviour

Comment: *I guess* that `CurrentContext.Test` is not available in `Setup` and `TearDown`. Are you sure that `CurrentContext` is null and not one of its properties?

Comment: The context is not null, while the properties are. I found some samples that use it in teardown, but with nunit 2.5. maybe in 2.6 is not working anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nunit-discuss/y11hIIi_jeY) you have to make sure you execute with the correct version of the  NUnit testrunner. The version has to be NUnit 2.6.2.

Try to run your tests with nunit-console with the correct version.

**Update:** I did set up a new project in VS2012 and added NUnit 2.6.2 and NUnit.Runners 2.6.2 using NuGet. With the Resharper Testrunner I did get no error but also no Console output, so I did run `NUnit.exe` from `<project-folder>\packages\NUnit.Runners.2.6.2\tools\`

This is the output I recieved:

[image]

The result looks ok.
I ran your example code above.

However, I had to modify your code so I could run it:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

[TestFixture]
public class UtilitiesTests
{
    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        //using console here just for sake of simplicity. 
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.FullName, TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status));
    }

    [Test]
    public void CleanFileName()
    {
        var cleanName = "my &file%123$99\\|/?\"*:<>.jpg";
        Assert.AreEqual("my &file%123$99\\|/?\"*:<>.jpg", cleanName);
    }
}
```

You should try to run your tests using NUnit.exe again, but before verify that you have the correct verison in Help -> About NUnit ...

Mine looks like this:

[image]

Comment: As I wrote in the comments, I tried also with the NUnit GUI of the 2.6.2, but no luck.

Comment: Please see my comment above.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. I was sure about the 2.6.2, but the dll, from nuget where from 2.6.2, while the gui was 2.6.1. So I removed and reinstalled everithing and now it works. Thanks a lot I missed a simple thing